# Cannot list any files while root

Tags: raspbian, sudo

I have a remotely hosted raspberry PI running Raspbian and Nginx and I want to modify the file `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` which is owned by root.

I'm very much a beginner with Linux (I did use Unix about 30 years ago but have forgotten everything!), so please bear with me.

I can log in as `user` via Putty and switch to root using `su` - but then I don't seem to be able to do anything. `ls -l` returns `0`.

However, if I log in as `user` using WinSCP I can see and navigate the folder structure but I can't do anything because everything is owned by root.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The question is a general Linux/Unix question about basic commands.  Perhaps search for a tutorial.

Comment: you are in a directory that contains no files

Comment: You tagged with `raspbian` but with it you cannot use `su` by default because you have to enter roots password then. root does not have a password on raspbian so you will always get `su: Authentication failure`. You must use `sudo`. Did you give root a password?

Comment: if I use 'su'  it asks for a password and I enter the 'user' password and it gives me access to 'root'

Comment: execute `su` to become root. Then execute these commands and paste its output into your question: `whoami`, `pwd` and `ls -a`.